# Sending Hexadecimal data through Serial Port Communication in Linux

Tags: c, linux, usb, hex

I have got a task of sending hexadecimal data to my COMPORT in linux. I have written this simple C code, but it sends only a decimal number. Can anyone help me in sending an hexadecimal bit.

Here is the code I have written

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

int number,n;
void main(void){
open_port(); 
}

  int open_port(void)
{
  int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */


  fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  if (fd == -1)
  {

perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyACM0 - ");
  }
  else{
     printf("Port Opened successfully\n");
     number = 1;
     while(number!=55){
     scanf("%d",&number);
      n = write(fd, "ATZ\r", number);
     if (n < 0)
     fputs("write() of 4 bytes failed!\n", stderr);
     }


}

  return (fd);
}
```

Please help

Thanks in advance :) :)

Comment: A hexadecimal value is the string representation of a binary value.  Each character of the string represents 4 bits(a nibble).  Serial ports can send data in 5,6,7, or 8 bit units.  So are you trying to send strings or numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`write` is defined as:

```
 ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

That is, it sends `count` bytes to `fd` from `buf`. In your case, the data is always the string "AZTR\r", plus undefined data after that (if count is > 5). Your program sends neither hexadecimal nor decimal data.

Do you want to send *binary* data or a string of *hexadecimal* characters?

For option one, you can use: `write(fd, somebuffer, len);`, where some buffer is a pointer to any set of bytes (including ints, etc).

For option two, first convert your data to a hexadecimal string using `sprintf` with `%02X` as the format string, then proceed to `write` that data to the port.

Comment: The only prob I am left with is that once after sending the hexadecimal it closes the port immediately. I need to keep it open till I wish so that i can send as many bytes as i wish in a go...here goes the main part of code....` while(check!=0){
         scanf("%x", buf);
         n = write(fd, buf, n);
  if(*buf==0){
          check = 0;
         }
         }` check is initially 1. But its not working. Any guess, why ??

Comment: I think I need to append the data to the file instead of writing it again and again. Can u help me with the syntax of appending the data at the end of the communication file.

Comment: @Prashant: `buf` should not change on calls to `write`. What are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with the code:

- The text read from the console is interpreted as decimal (`"%d"`); if you want it to be interpreted as hexadecimal, use `"%x"`.
- The `write()` is pathological.  The third argument is the number of bytes to write, not the value.  It should be either


    `n = write (fd, "ATZ\r", 4);   // there are 4 bytes to write to init the modem`

or

```
char  buf[10];
n = sprintf (buf, "%x", number);   // convert to hex
n = write (fd, buf, n);            // send hex number out port
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will take a hex string, and convert it to binary, which is what you want to actually send. the hex representation is for humans to be able to understand what is being sent, but whatever device you are communicating with, will probably need the actual binary values.

```
// Converts a hex representation to binary using strtol()
unsigned char *unhex(char *src) {
  unsigned char *out = malloc(strlen(src)/2);
  char buf[3] = {0};

  unsigned char *dst = out;
  while (*src) {
    buf[0] = src[0];
    buf[1] = src[1];
    *dst = strtol(buf, 0, 16);
    dst++; src += 2;
  }

  return out;
}
```