# sending string from pc to arduino in c++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, arduino

I am writing a C++ code to communicate with arduino-uno connected to serial port. I want to send a String like this to arduino : 'X20C20'

I know how to send single char to arduino like this :

```
int fd;
char *buff;

int open_port(void)
{

 fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
 if (fd == -1)
 {
  perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/kittens ");
 }
  else
   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

 return (fd);
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
open_port();
    int wr;


    char msg[]="h";

    /* Write to the port */
    wr = write(fd, msg, 1);
    close(fd);
  }
```

this code is used to send one char not a String, so what shall I do??

Comment: I would guess you can just write as many bytes as you want to rather than just 1 as you're currently doing.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555541/sending-hexadecimal-data-through-serial-port-communication-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that you have a good reason not to use write(fd, msg, strlen(msg)) with the parameter length. So I defined the function send_string:

```
void send_string(int fd, char* s)
{
    while( *s++ )
        write(fd, *s, 1);
}
```

use it in the main:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
open_port();
    int wr;


    char* msg ="Ciao Mondo!";

    /* Write to the port */
    send_string(fd, msg);

    // or use lenght parameter
    write(fd, msg, strlen(msg));

    close(fd);
  }
```

Angelo

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use write correctly?

```
write(fd, s, strlen(s));
```

You have to specify how many bytes you want to print on the file descriptor.

Maybe you can see more information about it reading this interesting book about advanced programming on linux: http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/alp-apB-low-level-io.pdf

Cheers

Comment: @user3613519 Do you need to send the terminator as well?  If so change the length to strlen(s)+1 in the above answer.