# How to send hex string to Serial Port?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I am developing a serial communication program to send and receive data between Host PC(Linux) and Microcontroller. Now I have to send hex bytes of data to MCU.
So How can I convert my buffer string data into hex string without using sprint/printf so user send string like "AA12CDFF1000001201" instead of "\xAA\x12\xCD\xFF\x10\x00\x00\x12\x01" to MCU. I also seen [Sending Hexadecimal to Serial Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555541/sending-hexadecimal-data-through-serial-port-communication-in-linux) but it not helpful as it says I can convert string to hex using sprintf but here in my case I don't want to use sprinf.
**Basically what I want is:
If user give input   = "AA12CDFF1000001201" I have to convert it into following format "\xAA\x12\xCD\xFF\x10\x00\x00\x12\x01" then write it to serial port.**

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
void main()
{
int fd;
fd = open("/dev/ttyf1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
char buff[]="\xAA\x12\xCD\xFF\x10\x00\x00\x12\x01";
write(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
close(fd);
}
```

Comment: * in my case I don't want to use sprinf due to some reason.* what is the reason? Why would you even send `9` bytes using `18` bytes long string?

Comment: I am sending 9 byte of Hex  data = "\xAA\x12\xCD\xFF\x10\x00\x00\x12\x01" which is tedious for user to input so I have to make it simple for user so someone just type "AA12CDFF1000001201" like as normal serial terminal app does where we user just typing as normal string.@tilz0R

Comment: So you failed with your question at first place. You want to convert string to bytes, for that you do NOT need sprintf at all. It is not even possible to do it.

Comment: Ok I changed it.@tilz0R

Comment: I gave you an answer below.

Comment: @raj123, isnt what u want a way to automatically insert \x in user input?

Comment: Yes that will work I can take string as input and insert \x at starting of every two character then send it to mcu @hessamhedieh

Comment: @raj123, so what is the actual question? are you looking for a way to insert \x in string? or it is something else i cant see?

Comment: Yes to insert \x in string will help me@hessamhedieh

Comment: Your send(...) knows nothing about fd descriptor. How does this compile? Also you used "send" but this is also a library routine name; bad practice.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the expected input format is a string with four chars per byte, i.e., a literal `\x` followed by the two hex digits? Could it be that you are looking to send only the actual bytes (e.g., just `X` instead of `\x58`), but the specs you read were using `\x` as an escape for them?

Comment: raj123, Do you now see a problem with `sizeof(buff)`? That is the size of a pointer, not the size of the array from the calling code.  This approach will not work.

Comment: \x is just used to send hex value rather than string. @Arkku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the fruitfull dicussion with Hessam and Arkku, a new version of the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* str2hexstr(char* inbuff) {

    char *outbuff;

    if (strlen(inbuff)%2) {
        outbuff=malloc((strlen(inbuff)*2+3)*sizeof(char));
        outbuff[strlen(inbuff)*2+2]='\0'; }
    else {
        outbuff=malloc(strlen(inbuff)*2+1*sizeof(char));
        outbuff[strlen(inbuff)*2]='\0'; }

    for (int strin=0,strout=0;strin<strlen(inbuff);) {
        outbuff[strout++]='\\';
        outbuff[strout++]='x';
        outbuff[strout++]=(!strin&&strlen(inbuff)%2)?'0':inbuff[strin++];
        outbuff[strout++]=inbuff[strin++];
    }
    return(outbuff);
}
int main()
{
    char inbuff1[]="123",inbuff2[]="1234";
    char *outbuff;

    outbuff=str2hexstr(inbuff1);
    printf("%s\n",outbuff);
    free(outbuff);
    outbuff=str2hexstr(inbuff2);
    printf("%s\n",outbuff);
    free(outbuff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I am giving input string: "12345678901" I am getting unwanted character at end of output string: \x01\x23\x45\x67\x89\x01�          @Stef1611

Comment: for every 11 character long input string it showing unwanted character � at end of output string. @Stef1611

Comment: @raj123 : You need to clarify your question further.  This outputs literally `"\x01\x23\x45..."`; that does not see to be what was asked for in the question.  `\01` is a character constant and I would expect the required output to to be a single character with the bit pattern 00000001, not _four_ characters.

Comment: @Clifford   question is about sending hex string "\x01\xAA" to serial port.

Comment: @raj123: Fair enough (though unusual), but your clarification needs to be added to the question not in a comment.  The code fragment in your question is misleading because that is not what `buff[]` contains.

Comment: @Clifford ok I will modify my question in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

### Convert from string to bytes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* Dummy input */
char input[] = "11121314151617181920";
uint8_t output[32];

/* Convert input char to int */
uint8_t
char2byte(char c) {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        return c - '0';
    } else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
        return c - 'A' + 10;
    } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') {
        return c - 'a' + 10;
    }
    return 0;
}

int
main() {
    size_t len;

    /* String must be even */
    len = strlen(input);
    if (len & 1 == 0) {

    }
    /* Process all inputs, 2 chars for single byte */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len / 2; ++i) {
        output[i] = char2byte(input[2 * i]) << 4;
        output[i] |= char2byte(input[2 * i + 1]);
    }

    /* Test, expected is 0x13 */
    printf("Test output[2] = %02X\r\n", (unsigned)output[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

If you run the code: `Test output[2] = 13`

### Convert from bytes to string

Something like this. Goal is to translate each nibble of each byte to char. This means output length is twice of your initial buffer size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* Output array */
char output[128];

/* Dummy input data array */
char data[] = {0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x00, 0x5A};

/* Convert each nibble to char */
char num2char(uint8_t num) {
    if (num < 10) {
        return num + '0';
    } else if (num < 16) {
        return num - 10 + 'A';
    }
}

int
main() {
    size_t i;
    printf("Hello World\r\n");

    /* Process all bytes */
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]); i++) {
        /* Generate it twice, for high and low nibble */
        output[2 * i] = num2char((data[i] >> 4) & 0x0F);
        output[2 * i + 1] = num2char((data[i]) & 0x0F);
    }
    /* Trailing zero for string */
    output[2 * i] = 0;

    printf("Output: %s\r\n", output);

    return 0;
}
```

When you run the code:

```
Output: 121314005A
```

Comment: Your string to byte is not what I needed in my code.I have to write this command to serial port "\xAA\x12\xCD\xFF\x10\x00\x00\x12\x01" instead of I need to make user friendly input like this "AA12CDFF1000001201"

Comment: Then your question is mature to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, not a clean code but should do the job

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void hexify(const char *input, char *output)
{
    int i = 0;
    int o = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(input[i] == 0) break; 
        output[o++] = '\\';
        output[o++] = 'x';
        output[o++] = input[i++];
        if(input[i] == 0) break; 
        output[o++] = input[i++];
    }
    output[o] = 0;
}

 int main()
 {
     char test[]="112233AA"; //user input
     if((strlen(test) % 2) && strlen(test) != 1)
         printf("Input is not in correct format");
     else
     {
         char *out = malloc(2 * strlen(test) + 1);
         hexify(test, out);
         printf("%s", out);
         free(out);//dont forget this
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char inbuff[]="AA12CDFF1000001201";
    char *outbuff;

    if (strlen(inbuff)%2) {
            printf("error : strlen is odd");
            exit(1);}
    outbuff=malloc((strlen(inbuff)*2+1)*sizeof(char));
    for (int strin=0,strout=0;strin<strlen(inbuff);) {
        outbuff[strout++]='\\';
        outbuff[strout++]='x';
        outbuff[strout++]=inbuff[strin++];
        outbuff[strout++]=inbuff[strin++];
    }
    outbuff[strlen(inbuff)*2]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",outbuff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why there should be a problem with odd string length?

Comment: @hessamhedieh If each byte is supposed to be represented by two hex digits, an odd length indicates that this isn't the case and it's not possible to know which byte is missing a nybble. (Your answer assumes that it's the last, but if this is input from the user, they could have made the mistake anywhere.)

Comment: I supposed that the number of characters must be even because 1 byte is two hex digits. With an even number of character, I do not know where to add an extra 0. At the beginning or at the end of inbuff ? Perhaps, @raj123 could precise. In your code, with an even number of character, you will obtain \xAA\x1F\xE (for example). What does it means 0E or E0 ?

Comment: @Arkku, sure you are right, but when `user` is playing a role, things go wired, what if user just wants to send say number 5 to board, from my experience forcing them to write 05 will lead to many problems regarding users complaining app is not working or is not user friendly.

Comment: @Stef1611, if u have any test that causes my code to fail, please feel free to provide, but AFAICT, my code handles even and odd scenarios with no problem.

Comment: @hessan hedied. I have not said that your code does not handle even character. I just have said that it could be a problem if the user enters an input string with an even number of character. One byte is two hex digits. It is just a sanity check. Otherwise, our code are very similar. And yours is better because you write a function to do it.

Comment: @hessamhedieh If the input is `123`, your odd-byte special case sends it as `\x12\x3` whereas the user might expect `\x1\x23`. (Considering the values, the latter would be `0x123` which corresponds to what they wrote, and you would send `0x1203`, which is effectively inserting a zero in the middle.) I would argue that the only time this "feature" is acceptable is when the input is exactly 1 digit, i.e., `1` becomes `\x1`. If the input is normally a multi-byte string, is it worth introducing this surprising special case to save 1 character?

Comment: @hessamhedieh As for "forcing them to type 05" not being user friendly, if we are talking about a program where the user is typing data as hex digits in a terminal, I would think that the user is someone who wants to ensure that these hex bytes are sent correctly (and thus might value being guarded from the program trying to guess what they mean), and not someone who wants to press one key fewer. =) In fact, if I were such a user myself, I would prefer the bytes to be space-separated.

Comment: @Arkku, your point is not arguable, have to admit i didnt think to that, edited my answer

Comment: @raj123 Could you clarify this point ? Is it possible to have an odd string length ? If yes, could you confirm that input string : "123" must be converted in output string "\x01\23" ?

Comment: @Stef1611 Yes for odd string length zero can be added at starting of output string.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I convert my buffer string data into hex string .... so user send ... ?
>
> give input = "AA12CDFF1000001201" I have to convert it into following format "\xAA\x12\xCD\xFF\x10\x00\x00\x12\x01" then write it to serial port.

When the intermediate storage to a buffer is not needed, this is quite simple.

Convert 2 characters<sup>1</sup> of the original *string* at a time to a byte, writing each byte per iteration.

```
#include <ctype.h>

void write_hex_string(const char *hs) {
  while (isxdigit(hs[0]) && isxdigit(hs[1])) {
    char buf[3] = { hs[0], hs[1], '\0' };
    unsigned char value = (unsigned char) strtol(buf, 0, 16);
    write(fd, &value, sizeof value);
    hs += 2;
  }
}
```

Sample use

```
write_hex_string("AA12CDFF1000001201");
```

---

If code can change the original *string* as part of the process, life is easy too.  As there is a convenient location to store the conversion.

```
void write_hex_string(char *hs) {
  char *pair  = hs;
  size_t length = 0;
  while (isxdigit(pair[0]) && isxdigit(pair[1])) {
    char buf[3] = { pair[0], pair[1], '\0' };
    hs[length++]  = (unsigned char) strtol(buf, 0, 16);
    pair += 2;
  }
  write(fd, hs, length);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>  As long as the 2 characters are both hexadecimal digits: ['0'-'9', 'A'-'F', 'a'-'f'].